# Parametrize references of generic type list as list<String>

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that returns List. When I use something like

```
List aList = myObj.getList("1");
```

It says Raw type. References to generic types should be parametrized.

When I use

```
List<String> aList = myObj.getList("1");
```

It says  either add cast to List  or change to List

I am not sure why ? Please suggest. 
PS: I am directly creating aList. There is no preceding 
`List aList = new ArrayList();`

Comment: What does `myObj.getList` return?  A raw `List`?

Comment: It returns a list<rstring>

Comment: Can you show us the full signature of your method? From what it says there we can presume it is just defined as List getList(String)

Comment: Please provide a little more information and code, code, code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a near certainty that you have declared the return type of `getList` to be the raw type `List` instead of `List< String >`.  Even if the body of `getList` works with explicitly-typed generic lists, the return type declaration determines the way the compiler types an expression  which involves a call to that method.

Comment: I am using IBM Infosphere streams as middleware here. These are all predefined things there .. will try to dig and come up with answer. But if you do not mind .. can you do a if else answer to this Q. Like it it returning X then this is what it is .. otherwise ..